# Blender render result not displying correctly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

[image]

The actual rendered png shows nothing at this pixel(white circle), because alpha is 0.

But Render result window still has some color visible(white circle).You can see its alpha value as well in this picture above.

Is there a way making render result showing exact the same thing png does?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.